# clone backbone model attributes

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-model

I have one backbone model containing 10 attributes, Now I want 5 attributes ( out of this 10 attributes ), to be copy/clone in my another newly created model. I can do this thing with getting/setting individually, but I want to know, is there any better/simple way to do this?

example :
modelfirst {fld1:value1, fld2: value2 ....}

new modelsecond().set({fld1: modelfirst.attributes.fld1 .... })

I want to do like this:

new modelsecond().set( modelfirst.get('fld1','fld2') });

do some one have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Underscore's methods (since it's required by Backbone, you have access to it):

```
new modelsecond(_.pick(_.clone(modelfirst.attributes), 'fld1', 'fld2', ...))
```

To select all the lower case attributes, you should be able to do

```
new modelsecond(_.pick(
  _.clone(modelfirst.attributes),
  _.select(_.keys(modelfirst.attributes), 
           function(attr){ return /^[a-z]+$/.test(attr) }))
```

Comment: thanks @david, can we do all property name in lowercase?

Comment: my all attribute name in first model in upper case (eg. FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME ), but I want to copy/clone with value in second model in lower case (eg. firstname, lastname ).